# How do I enable an auto download of newly installed Metro Apps?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, windows-store

I have multiple devices running Windows 8, and would like to sync up the apps that I install on one between the others.  Is there a way to enable auto download and installation of apps purchased within Metro Store?

Comment: Are you using the same account on both?

Comment: @TomWijsman yes I am.

Answer (score 4):

There is currently NO functionality to automatically "download" apps that you have already purchased on other devices. However, your app states will sync across devices. For example, the Kindle app knows which page of Shades of Grey you were reading on Device A. Open Shades of Grey on Device B, and voila! Pick up where you left off. To my understanding, MS deliberately opted to NOT automatically download apps based on account because there will likely be many apps that you will use on your phone or tablet but not on your desktop PC. Wordament is a good example for me. I play this on the phone and tablet, but don't have touch capability on my desktop, so the game is nearly impossible to play. Here is a great article on Sinofsky's blog if you're interested.  [Signing in to Windows 8 with a Windows Live ID](https://web.archive.org/web/20151122031116/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/b8/archive/2011/09/26/signing-in-to-windows-8-with-a-windows-live-id.aspx)

[windows-8](/questions/tagged/windows-8) [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) [efficiency](/questions/tagged/efficiency) [app](/questions/tagged/app)

Comment: Sad day.  It would be nice if they added this functionality.  Would make life a little easier.

Comment: Agreed. I totally understand why you would want this functionality. I have pined for it myself :) However, I also have a bunch of stuff on my RT tablet that I don't need on my desktop and a bunch on the desktop that won't even run on the tablet yet. MS's Solitaire is a good example. Still bummed about that :) I forgot to mention... in the store... if you swipe from the top or right click for the top app bar, you will see a tab for "Your Apps". This will display all the apps that are available to install on the current device. You can select multiples and install in one step.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at these pages from Microsoft and the Windows App Store, it doesn't look like there is any sync option right now.

Both [this page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/windows-store-install-apps-five-pcs) and [this page](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows-8/install-apps-windows-store#1TC=t1) say that you can install apps that you own on up to 5 PCs, but they also specify that you must do it from each computer you want to install the app on. "From the list of the apps you own that aren't installed on this PC, choose the ones you want to install, and then tap or click Install."

So unfortunately, it doesn't look like this functionality exists right now.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies within installing an app from Windows Store that automates your work: [**Task Robot**](http://www.userware-solutions.com/apps/task-robot.aspx).

It acts as a robot and do some repetitive task we do such as For example, schedule sending emails, **downloading applications** or transforming text automatically for you. It has worked fine for me you can give it a try – it's available for both 32 bit and 64 bit.

It is also available in Windows Store.

Comment: It seems like you would have to install this on each machine and tell it to download every new application.  Doesn't that defeat the purpose?