# How can I install an app I bought with my Microsoft Account on my kid's local account?

Tags: security, windows-8, windows-store

My kids can't buy an app. But I can. And I can install on up to 5 different machines/profiles.  What are the steps for me to be able to install an app I bought with my Microsoft Account on my kid's local account (or on my kid's Microsoft Account that can't buy anything)?

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/490191/how-do-i-enable-an-auto-download-of-newly-installed-metro-apps

Comment: Not a duplicate. This question is about a different profile.

Comment: Ohh for a local account. My apologies. I thought you two were running the same Live ID.

Answer (score 2):

- Open the Windows Store and you will be prompted to log on with your Microsoft Account. Log on with the MS account.
- You can then select and install any of the apps that you have purchased. That app will then be available for the other user account.
- When you are finished, log off your MS account.

Comment: Doesn't this save the Microsoft Store credentials though? The kid could then go and buy other apps, or use apps that you don't want to be available to the kid.

Comment: Doesn't logging out clear the credentials?

Comment: Hmm. That may be the case, but then wouldn't it remove any apps that were tied to the account?

Comment: It doesn't do that, as least not right now.

Comment: What if my kid has a Microsoft Account but just can't buy apps?

Comment: I would imagine you would have to relogon to his account afterwards.